# Linux C dumping process memory region and search for string issue

Tags: c, regex, linux, proc

I have a little C code that dumps a process memory then tries to REGEX match a string. All goes well if I want to dump the process but REGEX fails, or I wrongly search the memory buffer. Any idea?

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <regex.h>

void dump_region(int fd, off64_t start, off64_t end)
{
        char buf[4096];
        int a, i;
        regex_t re;
        regmatch_t pm;

        a = regcomp(&re, "([0-9]{10,20})", REG_EXTENDED);

        if(a!=0)
            printf(" -> Error: Invalid Regex");

        lseek64(fd, start, SEEK_SET);
        while(start < end) {
         int rd;

         rd = read(fd, buf, 4096);
         //write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, rd); // HERE dumping is OK
         a = regexec(&re, &buf[0], 1, &pm, REG_EXTENDED); // something I do wrong here
         if(a==0) {
             for(i = pm.rm_so; i < pm.rm_eo; i++)
                 printf("%c", buf[i]);
                 printf("\n");
         }
         start += 4096;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *maps;
        int mem;
        pid_t pid;
        char path[BUFSIZ];

        if(argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s pid\n", argv[0]);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        pid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
         perror("ptrace");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/maps", pid);
        maps = fopen(path, "r");

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
        mem = open(path, O_RDONLY);

        if(maps && mem != -1) {
         char buf[BUFSIZ + 1];

         while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, maps)) {
                off64_t start, end;

                sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end);
                dump_region(mem, start, end);
         }
        }

        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
        if(mem != -1)
         close(mem);
        if(maps)
         fclose(maps);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT:

Tried another version, still something going wrong or something I just miss...

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <regex.h>

void dump_region(int fd, off64_t start, off64_t end)
{
        char buf[4096];
        int status,i;
        int cflags = REG_EXTENDED;
        regmatch_t pmatch[1];
        const size_t nmatch=1;
        regex_t reg;
        const char *pattern="([0-9]{10,20})";

        regcomp(&reg, pattern, cflags);

        lseek64(fd, start, SEEK_SET);
        while(start < end) {
                int rd;

                rd = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);
                if(rd > 0)
                {
                  buf[rd] = '\0';
                  status = regexec(&reg, buf, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
                  if(status == REG_NOMATCH)
                        printf("No Match\n");
                  else if(status == 0){
                        printf("Match:\n");
                        for (i=pmatch[0].rm_so; i<pmatch[0].rm_eo; ++i) {
                                putchar(buf[i]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                  }
                  regfree(&reg);
                  return;
                }
                start += 4096;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *maps;
        int mem;
        pid_t pid;
        char path[BUFSIZ];

        if(argc < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s pid\n", argv[0]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        pid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
                perror("ptrace");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/maps", pid);
        maps = fopen(path, "r");

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
        mem = open(path, O_RDONLY);

        if(maps && mem != -1) {
                char buf[BUFSIZ + 1];

                while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, maps)) {
                        off64_t start, end;

                        sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end);
                        dump_region(mem, start, end);
                }
        }

        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
        if(mem != -1)
                close(mem);
        if(maps)
                fclose(maps);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any help? Idea?

UPDATE. Seems the second version partially works but from about `1193` matches I get with an `egrep` from the dumped memory file I get only TWO with my code. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know much about regexp in C, but shouldn't `&buf[0]` be simply `&buf` to give the reference of the beginning of the buffer?

Comment: Dump to file, run `strings file | egrep 'your regex'`. Did that find it? If so, the regex is correct and the bit you're missing is the c-string extraction (as suggested in unwind's answer)

Comment: Yes, I did that, used same code but dumped to file then used strings with the exact REGEX and finds many matches.

Comment: I think my regex `for` loop is skipping the whole buffer and gets only the fist part because it skipps what comes after `start += 4096`. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the buffer you pass to `regexec()` is a valid string, which is should be. [The manual page for `regexec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex) describes the function as:

> `regexec()` is used to match a null-terminated string against the precompiled pattern buffer [...]

So, you must make sure the data being searched is a proper string, by doing something like:

```
rd = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);
if(rd > 0)
{
  buf[rd] = '\0';
  a = regexec(&re, buf, 1, &pm, REG_EXTENDED);
  /* ... rest of code ... */
}
```

This also protects against read errors, when `rd` will be `< 0`.

As a general note, realize that "streaming" a regular expression matcher isn't this trivial in general; what if the RE match straddles your read buffer size? Then you risk missing a match, since you only allow the matcher to see disjoint "windows" into the actual data.

Furter, as pointed out in [@xtmtrx's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182299/xtmtrx) comment, the data you're reading isn't text, it's binary. This means it will often contain lots of "strange" values, for instance embedded 0-bytes that will look (to `regexec()`) as string terminators. If one of those appear before some of the data you're looking for in one block, you will miss the data since `regexec()` won't read past the end of string.

One solution is to filter out the non-textual data before trying to match, use a loop and `isprint()`, for instance.

Comment: Still something wrong. If I dump the process memory to STDOUT and send to file with `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, rd)` I can grep for `"([0-9]{10,20})"` and find many matches but with my code no match, even the REGEX code works.

Comment: Maybe because the dumped memory is RAW data and not just text?